# How to make a clear button like in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uikeyboard

I am doing a my own number keyboard. I want to add clear button on textfield like in iphone. How can I do that ?

I want clear button like in this picture:

[image: clear button]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are creating the field in code you can use:

```
[textField setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
```

Options are

1. `UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing`
2. `UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing`
3. `UITextFieldViewModeAlways`
4. `UITextFieldViewModeNever`

Or if you are using interface builder:

[image]

Comment: So we use use it for customized keyboard as UIView ?

Comment: I mean I don't use default keyboard ! How can I put clear button in textfield?

Comment: I customize keyboard as I want add 1 more button (00).

Comment: @chhanmalin It doesn't matter which keyboard you are using, regardless of what keyboard is visible the `UITextField` has properties of its own, one of which is the "clear button"

Comment: @chhanmalin your comment makes no sense. What EXACTLY are you trying to do?

Comment: Thank you ! It works! sorry for making you not feel good !